# Does HTML allow placing buttons inside navigation section?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

The [spec says](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-nav-element) the following about the `<nav>` element (emphasis mine):

> The nav element represents a section of a page that **links to other *pages*** or to parts within the page: a section with navigation **links**.

It never specifically says that `<button>` is disallowed, and nowhere it says that only `<a>` elements should be used for navigation (yet it mentions "links"), but all the examples seem to be a bunch of anchors in lists. The [one example (11)](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#example-84241bb3) that isn't a list still has only anchor elements for navigation inside.

The [next example (12)](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#example-a9b1e533) shows an example of navigation within application, but uses anchors again.

**So, are button elements allowed inside `<nav>`?**

Comment: As you wrote _"It never specifically says that <button> is disallowed"_, but what are your concerns actually ?

Comment: If buttons are allowed, I'm wondering about the meaning of "link" repeated twice in the navigation element description. Does it imply anchor element? Why not "interactive element" or something? When I see "link", I don't think "button". I guess a more general question which would cover mine would be: "How is a _link_ defined in the spec"?

Comment: Basically you can put any HTML element inside the `<nav>`, but it will be semantically right to have `<a href="the-link-to-something">`. Thats what I understand :)

Comment: Related (not duplicate) question: [Can I have a nav element with no links in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35401399/1591669)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML 5.2, [section 4.8.](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/links.html#links) is about *links*:

> Links are a conceptual construct, created by `a`, `area`, and `link` elements, that represent a connection between two resources […]

As one would expect, the definitions of [`a`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/textlevel-semantics.html#the-a-element) ("a hyperlink"), [`area`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/semantics-embedded-content.html#the-area-element) ("a hyperlink"), and [`link`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/document-metadata.html#the-link-element) ("the link(s)" etc.), all refer to links, while the definitions of [`button`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/sec-forms.html#the-button-element) and [`input`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/sec-forms.html#the-input-element) don’t.

So:

- A [`nav`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/sections.html#the-nav-element) element should contain elements with `href` attribute (`a`/`area`/`link`). Otherwise it wouldn’t be warranted to use `nav` in the first place (exceptions aside).
- A `nav` element may also contain buttons. For example, a button that is used to toggle between showing all levels of the navigation, and showing only the top-level. (However, if the buttons are used for navigation, they should be links instead of buttons anyway.)

Comment: Thanks, the examples are very good. Would love to hear your interpretation of the spec regarding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52238547/should-i-use-a-button-or-a-link-if-the-url-doesnt-change as well.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5 Standards allows any kind of flow content inside of `<nav>`-tags and `<button>` tags are considered being flow content, but you should consider to avoid them for semantical reasons. Buttons based on `<button>` are UI elements which are exclusively javascript driven (or in some tricky scenarios by the default behavior of the browser when using forms) without any functionality or semantical reference towards an 3rd party reference. Therefor using `<button>`-tags inside of `<nav>`-tags makes no sense for clients/robots who do operate without considering javascript.

Modern UI-Frameworks like Bootstrap, Semantic-UI or others do provide the ability to implement buttons in multiple ways (as `<button>`-tags as well as `<a>`-tags). Taking such abilities into account, you should prefer to rely on `<a>`-tag based buttons for semanatic reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you define "allowed".

It is valid HTML, but you may want to read up on accessibility and the difference between a button (that should signal clickable actions) and a link (that should navigate somewhere).

http://web-accessibility.carnegiemuseums.org/content/buttons/

Comment: Actually I have a follow-up question on the button/anchor debate I'm having: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52238547/should-i-use-a-button-or-a-link-if-the-url-doesnt-change