# Should I use a button or a link if the URL doesn't change?

Tags: html, single-page-application, semantic-markup

I'm building an app which works only with JavaScript enabled (otherwise, an appropriate message is displayed). There are a couple of screens in the app: game, tutorial, settings, about/credits. They *look* like separate pages, but it's all a single-page app. There are **no URL changes** when navigating between the screens.

**Should I use a button or an anchor in this case?** It feels like an anchor, but there's no page to lead to, meaning that `href` would have to be `#`. Also an anchor will break common patterns such as opening in new tab/window (no URL change means the app will restart from scratch in a new tab).

Comment: From a UX point of view you don't want a navigation so you wouldn't want to use an anchor.
And according to the accessibility specs you should use a button when you want to fire some JavaScript on user interaction.
Here are two links http://www.webaxe.org/proper-use-buttons-links/ and http://web-accessibility.carnegiemuseums.org/content/buttons/

Comment: In every single-page application, you're firing JavaScript events when clicking on anchor tags. The "buttons are for JS" and "anchors are for pages" mantra doesn't hold anymore.

Answer (score 0):

UI-Elements who operate in the same environment should not serve fallbacks to another URL. From the semantic point of view `<buttons>` are the way to go, but sometimes the implementation of those when optical modifications require more effort as an simple `<a>`-tag would, an `<a>`-tag would be the better way, regardless of the semantic. A screen reader for example has only minimal differences between a button and an anchor and complex UIs who mimic the semantic behavior of buttons with other tags have issues with more weight when considering alternative tags.